How get a web API written in C# .NET 8.0 to send a 200 response to satisfy a CORS preflight request?
I built an ASP.NET Core 8.0 Web API which works fine in Google script and from a web site built from notepad. However  when I am trying to communicate with it from an external site, it throws a CORS error

Access to fetch at 'https://a.someting.edu/Newsletter/api/newsletter' from origin 'https://t4.something.edu' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status

My Program.cs file:
var MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                      policy =>
                      {
                          policy.WithOrigins("https://t4.something.edu")
                                .AllowAnyHeader()
                                .AllowAnyMethod();
                      });
});

builder.Services.AddControllers();

// context 
IConfiguration config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
    .AddCommandLine(args)
    .AddUserSecrets<Program>(true)
    .Build();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<NewsletterContext>(option =>
{
    option.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
});

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddTransient<IApiKeyValidation, ApiKeyValidation>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ApiKeyAuthFilter>();

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();

app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();

Frontend HTML JavaScript Code
<script>
        function send() 
        {
            var url = 'https://a.something.edu/News/api/news';
            var headers = {
                    'X-API-Key' : "something1234",
                    'Accept': "application/json",
                    'Content-Type': "application/json;charset=utf-8"
            };
            var data = {
                    "email" : document.getElementById("customerEmail").value
            };
            
            var payload = JSON.stringify(data);
            
            var options = {
                method: "POST",
                headers: headers,
                body: payload
            };
            
            try {
                var response = fetch(url, options);
            }catch(error) {
                alert('Error is : ' + error);
            }
            alert('Response is - ' + response);
        }
</script>

Included in my program.cs file is cors middleware that I found on Microsoft learn cors, same issue and am not sure I set that up correctly as I still have to set the response header on the web server to Access-Control-Allow-Origin = *. Which is verified by the web.config file:
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>

Controller code
 [Route("api/[controller]")]
 [ApiController]
 public class NewsletterController(NewsletterContext context) : ControllerBase
 {
     private readonly NewsletterContext _context = context;

     [HttpPost]
     public async Task<ActionResult<NewsletterItem>> PostNewsletterItem(NewsletterItem newsletterItem)
     {
        _context.Newsletter_Emails.Add(newsletterItem);

         try
         {
             await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

         }
         catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
         {
            throw;
         }
         return Ok("The record has been saved correctly");
     }
 }

Model code
namespace NewsletterEmails.Models
{
   public class NewsletterItem
   {
       [Key]
       public required string Email { get; set; }
    }
}

I tried to set the mode to no-cors, however that results in an unsupported media type error 415.

Firstly, I noticed that your controller routing should be api/Newsletter but in your fetch function, it's /News/api/news so that I'm not sure whether the API you've managed with CORS policy is the one you are trying to call. Then the CORS policy should be able to solve your issue, could you please try to run your api in your local application and then call the localhost url instead for test purpose? If running locally worked well, I'm afraid the issue might relate to server.

I meet a CORS error today when calling an API from SPA, the issue is having cookie credential in my request but my CORS policy doesn't have AllowCredentials(). Could you please check it？

@TinyWang When I was copying and pasting to stackoverflow here I shortened the api call, the actual call in the fetch is /Newsletter/api/newsletter  Run locally it runs as expected, however once published the code does not produce a 200 instead it is showing a 0 for status. Where do I insert the AllowCredientials()? Is it in the program.cs file?

thank you for your reply! Just put the AllowCredientials() behind .AllowAnyMethod() in your Program.cs and let's try it.

@TinyWang added in AllowCredientals() to the Program.cs file. However it did not make a difference. Still reporting a CORS error.  Error reads Access to fetch at 'https://something.edu/Newsletter/api/newsletter' from origin 'https://t4.something.edu' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status. I have full control of the server just not sure where this problem lies, is it a server issue or code issue?

Run locally it runs as expected, however once published the code does not produce a 200 instead it is showing a 0 for status. --> Then I don't think this is a code issue.

@TinyWang Thank you for your guidance. Where should I post my question as a server issue? Sorry I am new to server configuring or really hardware configuration as a whole. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Which server you are using? Any host container?I think you could create a new question about it so that it will gather more attention. I'm not an expert on server side maintance too.
